# Any other Technic parts with a pinhole slot like part 18940?

Tags: technic, piece-information, mechanical

I haven't kept up with new parts or sets for at least a decade, but recently when browsing BrickLink I ran into part [18940](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=18940):

[image]

This caught my attention as I'm working on a MOC project right now where a major sticking point has been reducing off-axis slop in sliding motion. This is a very nontrivial problem in Technic builds because liftarms are ever so slightly thinner than a stud gap. The above piece caught my eye because it employs elongated pin-hole slots (see below) to solve this problem which results in a relatively rigid sliding connection that introduces impressively little friction.

[image]

However, these pieces have several other drawbacks, with half-stud-wide walls that create awkward spacing, and generally a lot of bulkiness that's difficult to build around just to take advantage of the pin slots. So I would like to know: are there any other pieces I am unaware of that feature a pinhole-slot like this?

Comment: I would think if the element you have in mind existed prior to when the slider elements were designed, there would have been no need to design the slider elements. There haven't been any improvements on the sliders in more recent sets. Hence I think it safe to conclude that the element you have in mind does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After scanning the relevant Technic part subcategories (plain Technic, Connector, Gear, Disk, Figure Accessory, Liftarm, Panel, Plate, Steering) on Bricklink, I'd say there is at most one such part besides your example and its various stickered versions:

[Technic, Liftarm, Modified Bent Thick 1 x 11.5 Double](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32009#T=C)

[image]

But the length of the slot is ... probably less than what you need.

Comment: Yeah that came to mind, but it's unfortunately definitely not a useable length of slot.

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of [Technic Beam Frame 3 x 19 with 2 Center Cross Beams, 3 Openings Thick](https://rebrickable.com/parts/67491/technic-beam-frame-3-x-19-with-2-center-cross-beams-3-openings-thick/) being similar shape, with 3 elongated openings.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately those are just full brick-width openings, not pinhole-width which is the specific feature I'm looking for.  It looks like there probably just aren't any other occurrences of that feature.